# How to connect C++ with MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, database-connection

I started developing a C++ (**not visual C++**) application and it required database connection to MySQL database server,but i'm not able to find any complete and explained example about how to connect, and where to download a driver if necessary.I found [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) and i can't figure it out to proceed farther

I'm using g++ c++0x compiler in Ubuntu 14.04

I familiarize with Java, I'm now to C++

Comment: the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/index.html you provided has a complete guide for mysql connector, why not read it first?

Comment: @Jichao i'm getting a compilation error @ line #include "mysql_connection.h"

Comment: You need set the INCLUDE file path. IMHO, you'd better learning how to write makefile in linux first.

Comment: @Jichao can you suggest a tutorial for overcome this issue

Comment: google `gcc tutorial`.

Answer (score 4):

For creating MySQL Connection use the following code:

```
 MYSQL *hMysqlConn;
 MYSQL *hMysql;
 hMysql = mysql_init(NULL);
 hMysqlConn = mysql_real_connect(
                                hMysql,
                                conn_server.c_str(), 
                                conn_user.c_str(), conn_password.c_str(),NULL,
                                0, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS);
```

where conn_server,conn_user,conn_password are user defined values.

For executing a query use the following:

```
mysql_query(hMysqlConn, query.c_str())
```

where query is user defined sql query.
Hope this answer may find usefull for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **ubuntu OS**,you could simply **install MySQL Library** by using the following command:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

**libmysqlclient-dev**: This package includes Mysql database development libraries and header files.

You could include the header file by:

```
#include<mysql/mysql.h>
```

Comment: can you post a simple source code demostrate creating connection with a simple select query using libmysqlclient-dev libraries

Comment: I installed libmysqlclient-dev and simply imported #include <mysql/mysql.h> and compile and i'm getting a compilation error.
g++  -o bin/Debug/MySQL obj/Debug/main.o  pthread  
g++: error: pthread: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: You have to compile the program by linking the library using -lmysqlclient option.If you are using netbeans goto Property->Linker->Libraries->Add Option and add -lmysqlclient to it.